# Find where associated records exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How can I select only those Employees who have associated Tag records? In other words, only select employee records that have one or more tag records associated with them.

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :employees
end
```

The query below (which is wrong) will give you guys an idea of what I'm trying to do.

```
Employee.includes(:tags).where("tags.id != nil")
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [`.joins`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-joins)

```
Employee.joins(:tags)
```

The SQL this generates contains and `INNER JOIN` on the `tags` table, omitting `employees` table records who have no associated `tags` record.

Comment: In Rails 3 (and possibly other versions) this will not cover the case where the tag_id exists, but that specific tag object has been deleted.

Comment: If the association is many-to-many, this won't do what is specified. It finds all (employee, tag) **combinations**, not all employees that have (one or more) tags. Using joins as filters is not a good idea in general.